# How to get Facebook Additional Permissions with android sdk 3.0 beta?

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, facebook-android-sdk, beta

I'm developing a simple Facebook app for Android using the official sdk beta 3.0.

I would to get additional permissions for user logged (user_likes, user_interests, friends_likes, etc...)  without using the LoginButton (as explained here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) and, in fact, I'm getting the additional permissions with method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        List<String> permission=new ArrayList<String>();
        permission.add("user_birthday");
        permission.add("user_likes");
        permission.add("user_questions");
        permission.add("user_interests");
        permission.add("user_relationships");
        permission.add("user_groups");
        permission.add("user_religion_politics");
        permission.add("friends_birthday");
        permission.add("friends_interests");
        permission.add("friends_likes");
        permission.add("friends_groups");
        permission.add("friends_questions");
        permission.add("friends_relationships");
       // this.openSession();
          this.openSessionForRead(app_id, permission);

    }
```

and actually, it opens the login view asking for permission to have additional permissions.

Now, I would know how to obtain the additional permissions because, when I'm calling user.get****() it not showing other methods except those for base informations.

Thanks!

---

I'm getting a Null.pointer.exception using

> private GraphObject mUser; ... // Assign the user object you get from
>   a call to get the user's info
>
> String religion = mUser.getProperty("religion").toString();

here my logcat:

```
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.********.*****.Main$1.onCompleted(Main.java:123)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:248)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1197)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-08 14:21:47.908: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can additional permissions after the session has created. without closing the session

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("user_groups"));

            session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a method to the com.facebook.Session.java class within the Facebook Android SDK project:

```
public static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, StatusCallback callback, List permissions) {
    return openActiveSession(activity, allowLoginUI, new OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(permissions));
}
```

From your code you can then call directly

```
Session.openActiveSession(LoginActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {

            //YOU CALLBACK CODE

        }
    }

}, Arrays.asList("email","OTHER_PERMISSIONS_YOU_WANT_TO_REQUEST"));
```

Comment: I attempted to set read permissions like this : `authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));` and then tried to access the email like this `user.asMap().get("email")` but it always returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

GraphUser only has a limited set of common properties you can pull and read, ex: birthday. To read something else like say religion you could do the following:

```
private GraphObject mUser;
...
// Assign the user object you get from a call to get the user's info

String religion = mUser.getProperty("religion").toString();
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mUser is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to  the [Graph api explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). You just select right application and click create access token. Into popup dialog you can set prefered permission.

As you can see in the original example called: "SessionLoginSample" - after you receive TOKEN, you can call JSON file structure which is available from "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=insert_your_real_token&format=json"

That json file is response with all information that is available due to user's private settings.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Session.Builder bui = new Builder(this); //should be an activity
    Session session  = bui.build();
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(context);
    List<String> permission=new ArrayList<String>();
        permission.add("user_birthday");
        permission.add("user_likes");
        permission.add("user_questions");
        permission.add("user_interests");
        permission.add("user_relationships");
        permission.add("user_groups");
        permission.add("user_religion_politics");
        permission.add("friends_birthday");
        permission.add("user_location");
        permission.add("friends_likes");
        permission.add("friends_groups");
        permission.add("user_education_history");
        permission.add("friends_relationships");
        permission.add("email");

    openRequest.setPermissions(permission);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);//This will take care of the null pointer
    openRequest.setCallback(this);//the callback
    session.openForRead(openRequest);
```

**Session.setActiveSession(session);**
IS the missing line in your code... (and the builder)